# Most recent notification status bar

Tags: java, android

I want the unique id of upcoming notification. Is it possible to get the unique id in order to identify the recent notification?

```
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {

            sbn.getUiqueId();
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the public method is:

```
    StatusBarNotification.getId();
```

Comment: getId() give the id like if there is 3 notifications it give the same id like 1 for all of them